# Is it possible to do only the download part of apt-get/aptitude full-upgrade?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

When I go to internet cafe, I'd like to take that opportunity to upgrade the system. Sometimes though there is not electrical sockets in the cafe. To conserve batteries I'd like to be able to only do the "download" part of the upgrade process, and apply the new packages later, at home.

I know that I can just interrupt the `apt-get dist-upgrade` process just after it downloads the packages. I want to have a hands-free solution, that I can use in my custom `download-all-upgrades.sh` script.

It is possible to just download the package with `aptitude`, but it works only when I know the package name. It doesn't work with upgrade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass `apt-get` the `-d` option to only download the packages.

```
apt-get dist-upgrade -d
```

From `man apt-get`:

```
OPTIONS
    ...
    -d, --download-only
           Download only; package files are only retrieved, not unpacked or installed. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Download-Only.
```

From `man aptitude`

> -d, --download-only
>    Download packages to the package cache as necessary, but do not install or remove anything. By default, the package cache is stored in /var/cache/apt/archives.

Comment: Anyone following this answer should know that Aptitude ignores the `-d` flag if it's used for an interactive session (i.e. `aptitude -d` alone).